# How to do a MySQL query with AJAX without revealing db user password?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm new to JavaScript and AJAX. My experience is mostly in PHP. How can you do a MySQL query from JavaScript without revealing in the View HTML Source of the web browser the connection information for the MySQL database such as the db user's password? Thanks!

Comment: Simple answer: you can't. My recommendation would be to use some server-side language (PHP as you mentioned) to handle the connection. Remember that anything that executes in the client's machine can be viewed by the end user or any third-party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you don't perform the actual database query from the JavaScript code.  The fact that it's using AJAX doesn't move database connectivity to the client, it just allows you to request information from the server without refreshing the page (as well as potentially moving some of the UI logic to the client).

Your AJAX call would simply make a request to a PHP file in your website which could:

- Render part of a page, where the JavaScript code from the other page which called it would insert that markup into the open page.  Or;
- Render data, usually in JSON format, which the JavaScript code from the other page would read and use.

So let's say you have `PageA.php` which has a bunch of HTML and JavaScript.  You want some of that JavaScript to make an AJAX call to the server to get data.  You'd create a `PageB.php` which behaves just like any other PHP code, but instead of using HTML between the PHP code fragments (or in `echo` statements) it would use [JSON](http://www.json.org) syntax to represent the data being returned.

The JavaScript code on `PageA.php` would make an AJAX call to `PageB.php`, read the data that's returned, and use it in the HTML of `PageA.php` entirely client-side without having to refresh `PageA.php`.

Comment: So there isn't a way to pass a PHP Object directly to JavaScript that's secure? It must be written out to a file and then read back into an Object in JavaScript? I'm thinking about using AJAX to have it update timely data which comes from a SOAP request.

Comment: What makes you think that?  The security of transferring data from your server to an AJAX call is exactly the same as the security of sending any page response from the server to the client.  You can encrypt with SSL, etc.  AJAX is just an HTTP call like any other page, no more or less secure.  And what do you mean about "writing to a file and back into an object"?  You don't have to write the data to a file on the server, you'd just render it to the HTTP response exactly like HTML data.  It's just JSON format instead of HTML.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the security between the data on the server and what gets transmitted to the user's web browser for this application, but keeping the MySQL database secure. So it sounds like you create another php program to output json which the AJAX would read.

Comment: @Edward: That sounds about right, depending on how you define "a PHP program."  It's essentially another "page" on the site.  (It *could* be the same page, and just internally determine if it should render HTML or JSON.  But that gets more difficult to manage and it's generally best to separate the two.)  You definitely want to avoid exposing your MySQL server to direct internet connections as much as possible, regardless of whether or not AJAX is being used.  It's always best to keep the database behind an application API.

Answer (score 2):

You make your JavaScript request the information from a PHP script, which checks the user's login cookie (like any other page would) and queries MySQL, returning the information to the JavaScript in whatever form it needs (JSON, usually).

Comment: I see. So anything secure is done in PHP such as MySQL, SOAP requests, etc. and then pass it to JavaScript. How do you pass it to JavaScript from PHP then? What's the best way? Thanks!

Comment: I'm a newbie to this, but I think one approach is to have `page_1.php` which contains your `jQuery` and use jQuery's `getJSON` method to get results from EITHER a `php` file that has used `json_encode` on its results from the database OR just a pure `json` file, and then you will have the results of the `getJSON` method available to use as variables for manipulation with your jQuery.  I hope that is somewhat clear - this was a good video that got me on my way to understanding JSON - http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/an-introduction-to-json

Comment: this might also help:  http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/getting-started-with-javascript-object-notation-json-for-absolute-beginners/

Comment: and the php manual entry on `json_encode` with some clear examples:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php